# How can I check the DMD version in compile-time?

Tags: version, d, conditional-compilation, dmd

I can test that DMD is compiling the given code using `version(DMD){}`, but how can I check which version of it? (2.66/2.65 etc)

More concisely, I want to check that the `@nogc` modifier exists,
and if not - define a dummy one.

I came up with a workaround:

```
static if(!__traits(compiles, ()@nogc{}))
{
    struct nogc;
}
```

but is there a better way? for example even checking directly for the existence of that specific modifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the predefined `__VERSION__` constant.

See also the [std.compiler](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_compiler.html) module (`version_major` and `version_minor`, specifically) for an easier way to use it.

However, your workaround might be a better approach. It will allow the code to work correctly even for compiler builds between released versions.